# What is the possible setting for Codeigniter connecting to a SSH server with centOS and mariadb as database management?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, mariadb

The server I'm using is an ssh connection, which is ran by centOS, it uses LAMP as platform.

Because it is centOS, mariadb is the only available database management for it. I cannot install mysql via `sudo yum install mysql-server` command.

I've created a project using codeigniter in my local.

I'm having trouble connecting to the database. The error gives like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
```

The db setting in my codeigniter is:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '*server-ip-address*',
    'port' => '*server-port-number*',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root@999',
    'database' => 'listingapp_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I just thought that maybe my database setting is wrong.

Has it something to matter with the `dbdriver` setting?
I tried changing `mysqli` to `mariadb`, still no progress.

What could possibly be the valid setting that could co-inside with the server's centOS, mariadb?

I tried sudo iptables -vnL to check firewall and this is the result:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 10924 packets, 630K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
40905 5353K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
1860K 2702M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
    4   172 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
  158  9480 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  445 28059 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   57  2800 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2202

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1133K packets, 103M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: You can connect to mariadb with mysqli in codeigniter, no problem. It might be the centos firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: @ourmandave ah, I see. but how can I unblock a port? what is an example command?

Comment: Depends on what version of Centos you're running and if you're using firewalld or iptables. You should probably google that one.

Comment: @ourmandave I tried `sudo iptables -vnL`. I edited above for the result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now fixed my issue. It's a matter of opening the port I used then granting privilege to the root user in mysql.