# Connecting to multiple site in one server/ip, does port being used related?

Tags: apache, codeigniter, port, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

This problem is related to [Host Multiple Domains on One Server/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342338/host-multiple-domains-on-one-server-ip/47344475#47344475)

I firstly did the CI project in my localhost.

As such, there are some issues I encountered when connecting server-local, referred at [What is the possible setting for Codeigniter connecting to a SSH server with centOS and mariadb as database management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297899/what-is-the-possible-setting-for-codeigniter-connecting-to-a-ssh-server-with-cen?noredirect=1#comment81548235_47297899)

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

This command solved it. Opening port 3306.

Just opening port through the firewall, this solution solved the problem connecting my localhost to database server, I can access now the CI project.

Now my problem is I cannot access the CI when I deployed it at the same server/ip together with another project(phpList).

**ADDED NOTE:** as mentioned at the comments below.(Sorry for this late confirmation) There is no available DNS, so the applied servername,etc could be denied, that means I could only use server-ip address.

My question is, do I need to also setup the port in the vhost in my CI project same as to what port opened in my localhost-server problem?

The phplist vhost setting is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phplist.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phplist-3.0.5/public_html

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In my CI project, this is the vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName listcsv.com
    ServerAdmin admin@listcsv.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/citest/

        <Directory /var/www/citest>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried changing `<VirtualHost *:81>` into `<VirtualHost *:3306>` but I still failed on accessing.

Could I be missing some other settings for this? Could there be possible work-around? I'm in desperate need of help.

**UPDATES**:

So I tried adding another port to listen, in `httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
```

Tried to open `http://123.123.123.123:81`, there are no errors thrown but it seems to load very long.

Comment: Use `:80` in both VirtualHosts, make sure both `listcsv.com` and `hplist.example.com` point to the same (correct) IP address. From browser, use names (not address) to access. If it still fails, provide the exact error message.

Comment: @DusanBajic changed both to `:80`, tried to access `listcsv.com` and `phplist.example.com`. It fails, both gives me error of:

`This site can’t be reached

listcsv.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Did you mean http://listcv.com/?
Search Google for list csv
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

and

`This site can’t be reached

phplist.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Go to http://example.com/
Search Google for phplist example
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Did you "make sure both listcsv.com and hplist.example.com point to the same (correct) IP address"?

Comment: @DusanBajic does `*:80` not specify it? do I make it like `123.123.123.123:80`?

Comment: @DusanBajic tried it. Still the same.

Comment: No no no. Your client (browser) needs to know how to resolve `phplist.example.com` to the correct server IP address. [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is usually used for this, but you san also hardcode it in your workstation [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file

Comment: @DusanBajic Ah, I get now what you explained. I will try again. I will update if anything happens

Comment: @DusanBajic sorry I just confirmed this from someone. there's no bought dns by this server. So I could use only ip-addresses. Sorry for bothering.